# find the text and return its value, return 0 if the text is not found

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I need your help. Cannot figure out why the piece of code below doesn't work. I have a PivotTable where I look for a specific value with a function FIND and VLOOKUP and add it to a specific cell:

[image]

After the data update - there is no information about States duration of 10 - 19 days anymore. In this case when some category values are absent - I want to assign the 0 value to a specific cells.
I tried to achive it writing the following:

```
Dim x As Long
Dim Lookup_Range, RangeA As range

With Worksheets("Duration")

Set Lookup_Range = Worksheets("Duration").range("A1:B56")

On Error Resume Next
x = Lookup_Range.Find("1 - 9 days", range("A1"), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext).Row

Set RangeA = .range(.Cells(x, 1), .Cells(x + 4, 2))

If Not x <> "" Then

   .Cells(30, 7) = Application.VLookup("State1", RangeA, 2, False)
   .Cells(31, 7) = Application.VLookup("State2", RangeA, 2, False)
   .Cells(32, 7) = Application.VLookup("State3", RangeA, 2, False)
   .Cells(33, 7) = Application.VLookup("State4", RangeA, 2, False)

Else

   .Cells(30, 7) = 0
   .Cells(31, 7) = 0
   .Cells(32, 7) = 0
   .Cells(33, 7) = 0

End If

On Error Resume Next
x = Lookup_Range.Find("10 - 19 days", range("A1"), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext).Row

Set RangeA = .range(.Cells(x, 1), .Cells(x + 4, 2))

If Not x <> "" Then

   .Cells(34, 7) = Application.VLookup("State1", RangeA, 2, False)
   .Cells(35, 7) = Application.VLookup("State2", RangeA, 2, False)
   .Cells(36, 7) = Application.VLookup("State3", RangeA, 2, False)
   .Cells(37, 7) = Application.VLookup("State4", RangeA, 2, False)

Else

.Cells(34, 7) = 0
.Cells(35, 7) = 0
.Cells(36, 7) = 0
.Cells(37, 7) = 0

End If

End With
```

It only returns the right values when the first condition of IF is fulfilled.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Start by commenting out your On Error lines and debugging any errors.

Comment: @SJR without 'On Error Resume Next' I get the error message "Runtime Error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set"

Comment: it highlights the line x = Lookup_Range.Find("10 - 19 days", range("A1"), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext).Row , I suppose, because it cannot find the cell with "10 - 19 days"

Comment: Why not just use the normal vlookup function in the worksheet?

Comment: @Luuklag how? I need the information from the second column, and since I have State1, State2 and so on for every category (see "1 - 9 days" etc.), I thought I have to find first the right range of data to do a VLookup.

Comment: Yes I think it probably does mean that. You should add a check to avoid errors, but you need to find out why it doesn't find the value. First, use `sheets("Duration").range("a1")` in your Find statement.

Comment: @SJR it doesn't find the value, because when I run the code - I get a new data from the external excel file, and there is no "10 - 19 days" anymore

Comment: So what should happen if the value is not found?

Comment: From time to time some values will be absent. I want in case when the FIND function cannot find the given value, to get 0 in the second table (second table is on the same worksheet).

Comment: OK I see now. I have tidied up your code a little below so let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adds some checks that the values are found which should avoid the errors.

```
Sub xy()

Dim x As Long, r As Range

Dim Lookup_Range, RangeA As Range

With Worksheets("Duration")
    Set Lookup_Range = .Range("A1:B56")
    Set r = Lookup_Range.Find("1 - 9 days", .Range("A1"), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        x = r.Row
        Set RangeA = .Range(.Cells(x, 1), .Cells(x + 4, 2))
        .Cells(30, 7) = Application.VLookup("State1", RangeA, 2, False)
        .Cells(31, 7) = Application.VLookup("State2", RangeA, 2, False)
        .Cells(32, 7) = Application.VLookup("State3", RangeA, 2, False)
        .Cells(33, 7) = Application.VLookup("State4", RangeA, 2, False)
    Else
        .Cells(30, 7) = 0
        .Cells(31, 7) = 0
        .Cells(32, 7) = 0
        .Cells(33, 7) = 0
    End If
    Set r = Lookup_Range.Find("10 - 19 days")
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        x = r.Row
        Set RangeA = .Range(.Cells(x, 1), .Cells(x + 4, 2))
        .Cells(34, 7) = Application.VLookup("State1", RangeA, 2, False)
        .Cells(35, 7) = Application.VLookup("State2", RangeA, 2, False)
        .Cells(36, 7) = Application.VLookup("State3", RangeA, 2, False)
        .Cells(37, 7) = Application.VLookup("State4", RangeA, 2, False)
    Else
        .Cells(34, 7) = 0
        .Cells(35, 7) = 0
        .Cells(36, 7) = 0
        .Cells(37, 7) = 0
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You have just saved my project. Thank you very much! It works like I want.